# Will Ubuntu 20.04.3 work on DELL XPS M1730?

Tags: dell, laptop, lts

Dell XPS M1730 - Intel Core 2 Duo T9300 (2,50 GHz, 800 MHz FSB, 6 MB L2-cache), Windows Vista Home Premium, 17" UltraSharp TFT WUXGA (1920 x 1200) + 2.0 MP webcam, 4096 MB Dual Channel DDR2 SDRAM, 120 gb WD green SSD, DUAL SLI 512 MB NVIDIA GeForce 8800GTX, DVD+/-RW, 9-cell lithium-ion battery, Bluetooth + Dell Bluetooth 2.0-stereoheadset, 802.11n, Sound Blaster Audigy ADVANCED HD Audio

Comment: Given the age of the machine and the resources on that machine, you’ll likely want to use one of the lighter flavours, such as Ubuntu MATE, Xubuntu, or Lubuntu. Bodhi Linux would also be a solid choice, but is not supported on this site 

Comment: Yes it works pretty fast. Just need to update your drivers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Ubuntu will probably work on it - at least work better than Visa which is no longer supported. The best way to check is to first boot using an Ubuntu Live USB or CD.

See here for more information:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started

Comment: Will I be able to Rufus it to USB?

Comment: Here's the tutorial: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started